# Margin relative to an element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, alignment

**How can I align an element beneath a different element with an unknown height relatively?**

What I tried is creating a converter that gets the margin of the different element and adds the wanted space between them but I don't know how I can add the different element's height to really achieve what I want.

This is the converter I'm talking about:

```
public class MargConv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType.Equals(typeof(Thickness)))
        {
            Thickness thick = (Thickness)value;
            thick.Top += 51;
            thick.Left = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter) == 1 ? 22 : 151;

            return thick;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Thickness thick = (Thickness)value;
        thick.Top -= 51;
        return thick;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The XAML I'm talking about:

```
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="699" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="699" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456">
                <TextBlock Name="areat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,33,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="איזור מגורים:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Name="area" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Area}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="{Binding ElementName=area, Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource margconv}, ConverterParameter=1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="תיאור משרה:" />
                <TextBlock Name="content"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding ElementName=area, Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource margconv}, ConverterParameter=0}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding ElementName=content, Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource margconv}, ConverterParameter=1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="תאריך עדכון:"/>
                <TextBlock Name="date" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding ElementName=content, Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource margconv}, ConverterParameter=0}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Date}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>

                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding ElementName=date, Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource margconv}, ConverterParameter=1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="דוא&quot;ל לחזרה:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox Name="email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="{Binding ElementName=date, Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource margconv}, ConverterParameter=0}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding RetEmail}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303"/>
                <Button Content="שלח קו&quot;ח" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding ElementName=email, Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource margconv}, ConverterParameter=1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="SendResume"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I want to align the textblocks beneath the other textblocks, but without knowing their height (their text it taken from some data source and therefor it's no static => height is changing).

Comment: `How can I align an element beneath a different element with an unknown height relatively?` - Use a `StackPanel`, or otherwise a `Grid` with 2 `RowDefinitions`. Anyways post the relevant XAML. You don't need any converters for this.

Comment: +1 @HighCore because it sounds/looks like you're way over-complicating things so far.

Comment: If you are trying to display some kind of temporary overlay, a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) or an [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) may be a solution.

Comment: @HighCore I edited with the XAML I'm talking about. (though my question was supposed to be general).

Comment: @DanBarzilay Dude you're doing it all wrong. That's not the correct way to do layout in WPF. Create the proper `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` for that grid and position each element accordingly.

Comment: @HighCore I know, I'm new to this :/ can you give me an example?